# Receiving PermissionError while reading excel file from one folder and outputting to csv file in another folder using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv

I have 2 folders named as `Excel` and `CSV`. The Excel folder contains excel files with prefix "_Updated" that I would like to convert to CSV with UTF-8 encoding, and If the file contains multiple sheets then new `csv` file will be created based on sheet. However, when I run below code, I am receiving PermissionError as shown below not sure what is wrong with below code ?

Thanks in advance for your time!

**Code:**

```
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

CSV_FILE_PATH='/Excel'
CSV_FILE_SAVE='/CSV'

for file in Path(CSV_FILE_PATH).glob('*_Updated.xlsx'):
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    print(file, wb.active.title)
    for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
        with open(CSV_FILE_PATH, 'r+') as f_in, open(CSV_FILE_SAVE, 'w',encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
            content = f_in.read()
            spamwriter=csv.writer(f_out)
            for row in wb[sheetname].rows:
                spamwriter.writerow([cell.value for cell in row])
```

**Error:**

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2ef7cc7706ca> in <module>
     10     print(file, wb.active.title)
     11     for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
---> 12         with open(CSV_FILE_PATH, 'r+') as f_in, open(CSV_FILE_SAVE, 'w',encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
     13             content = f_in.read()
     14             spamwriter=csv.writer(f_out)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Excel'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `PermissionDenied` error because you are attempting to open a directory for reading as if it were a file. You will get this error on Windows if you attempt a file operation on a directory.

This is where you attempt to read in a directory, in your case, the directory `/Excel`:

```py
        with open(CSV_FILE_PATH, 'r+') as f_in, ... :
```

`f_in` is later used in the line `content = f_in.read()`. However, you aren't using `content` anywhere, so I suggest you get rid of it, as then you can also get rid of the `open(CSV_FILE_PATH, 'r+') as f_in` part of the line above. That should sort out your problem:

```py
        with open(CSV_FILE_SAVE, 'w',encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
            spamwriter=csv.writer(f_out)
            for row in wb[sheetname].rows:
                spamwriter.writerow([cell.value for cell in row])
```